# reconnect socket after sleep

Tags: javascript, html, perl, websocket

I am trying to learn sockets in Perl. It is common that user closes the lid and socket connection gets disconnected.Is there any way that the server can get to know about client going to sleep mode. Please Help.I am using Net::WebSocket::Server

Answer (score 1):

The usual means of detecting a socket that was not actively closed, but has suddenly become unreachable is for a heartbeat packet to be sent on some agreed upon schedule.  The other end of the socket is supposed to response with a heartbeat response each time it receives a heartbeat packet.

If the server sends out the heartbeat and does not receive a response in a reasonable amount of time, then it can assume that the client is no longer actively connected.

Socket libraries like `socket.io` implement this very technique for detecting when the connection has gone dead for use with websockets, but the same technique can be used with any type of socket.

The heartbeat can be used from either end of the connection (just depending upon how you want to do it and what each side expects).  So, if the server is sending the heartbeat, a client could assume that if it goes X amount of time without receiving any heartbeat requests, then it's connection to the server must have gone dead so it should close the socket and reconnect.

Comment: thanks for explaining about this. Can you please give me the link to know more about this or any demo?